# Install latest umbrello version

Tags: 16.04, ppa, uml

How to Install latest **umbrello** version under Ubuntu 16.04? I have 2.18 (15.12) in Ubuntu 16.04/Mint 18. Build from sources or some PPA available?

I see [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/umbrello) contains only 2.21 (16.12) version but for newer Ubuntu version. However [latest version](https://umbrello.kde.org/developers.php#changelog) is 2.22 (17.04)

Here http://archive.neon.kde.org/user/pool/main/u/umbrello/ we have the latest but it requires `libqt5core5a (>= 5.7.1+dfsg)`. Any ideas? Build custom deb package: I know how to build src.rpm - how to do the same in Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: @Alban, anyway: at least 2.21 and 2.22 when it will be released.

Comment: Why do you mention "Ubuntu 16.04/Mint 18"?

Comment: @DKBose, why not? :) I have it installed and umbrello version is a little bit old in it. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make build directory, cd into it
2. Download package source codes:

   ```
   dget http://archive.neon.kde.org/user/pool/main/u/umbrello/umbrello_17.04.1-0neon+16.04+build22.dsc
   ```
3. Unpack them:

   ```
   dpkg-source -x umbrello_17.04.1-0neon+16.04+build22.dsc
   ```
4. Cd source directory:

   ```
   cd umbrello_17.04.1
   ```
5. Run (optional: if You want to change package changelog) and edit changelog:

   ```
   dch -i
   ```
6. Build the package:

   ```
   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
   ```

   of if in case of any error:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-buildpackage
   ```

> **Note.** For successful build change string `usr/share/metainfo` to `usr/share/appdata` in `umbrello_17.04.1/debian/umbrello.install` file.

7. In case of error install missed dependencies, in my case it was:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install kdoctools-dev kinit-dev kio-dev libboost-dev \
   libkf5archive-dev libkf5auth-dev libkf5completion-dev libkf5config-dev \
   libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5guiaddons-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev \
   libkf5parts-dev libkf5service-dev libkf5texteditor-dev \
   libkf5widgetsaddons-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev \
   libqt5svg5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev pkg-kde-tools qtbase5-dev
   ```
8. Build the package again:

   ```
   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
   ```
9. Install result package from build directory:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i umbrello_17.04.1-0neon+16.04+build22_amd64.deb
   ```

Comment: Compile most of the time works +1 ;)

Comment: I unstable however :) Will try 2.21 as well :)

Comment: If it's `umbrello` that is unstable I guess it's just the way it is. back in the days when I was working with it at `14.04` a lot of times I experience crashs, etc.

Comment: @Ravexina, 2.18 worked fine without any crash, will try 2.21 however.

Comment: @Ravexina, latest version 2.22 released on 12 of May from here http://archive.neon.kde.org/user/pool/main/u/umbrello/ works stable for me.